# not working with webview in xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, ios6

NSString *googleMapsURLString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&output=embed" ,floatLati, floatLongi];

Comment: Err, I think a bit more detail is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 NSString *googleMapsURLString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&output=embed",floatLati,floatLongi];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString1];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```